# UPDATE parts of JSON doc with JSON_SET() instead of setting whole doc new

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to update parts of a JSON doc inside a MySQL database table.

The field name in the database: `jdata`

#### The Problem

I **do not** want to set it like `jdata = '{_whatever_}'`,
because I would loose keys.

I **need to preserve** existing keys (e.g. `key1`, `key3`)
and only set `key2` to its new designated value `999`.

#### The JSON doc

```
{
  "calculation":{
    "key1": 100,
    "key2": 200,
    "key3": 300
  }
}
```

#### The PHP/MySQL

```
$a = json_encode(['key2' => 999], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$sql =
"   UPDATE  svtr.auftrag
    SET     jdata = JSON_SET(jdata, '$.calculation', '{$a}')
    WHERE[...]
";
```

> Using the full path like so: `JSON_SET(jdata, '$.calculation.key2', 999)` is no option here, since the original JSON doc is much more complex and I would have to iterate many keys. Think of it like having 30 key/value pairs and needing to update 29 of them.

Hope anyone can make sense of my ramblings ... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sad! First time no one says nothing :(

Comment: did you ever figure this out?